# Python domain name list regex

Tags: python, regex

I wish to get all the the domain names in the given string using python. 
i have tried the below but i am not getting the o/p as expected

```
str = "ctcO6OgnWRAxLtu+akRCFwM asu.edu zOiV6Wo6nDnUhQkZO4XTySrTRwLMgozM9R/LyQs2r+Pb tarantino.cs.ucsb.edu,128.111.48.123 ssh-rsa 9SMF4U+qJW03Bh1"
list = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,10}', str)
print list
```

I want the output as:

```
asu.edu , tarantino.cs.ucsb.edu
```

but what I get is:

```
[('asu.', ''), ('ucsb.', '')]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: please don't overwrite built-in types, use `my_str` and `my_list` names instead if you don't have any *meaningful* names for them

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import re
my_str = "ctcO6OgnWRAxLtu+akRCFwM asu.edu zOiV6Wo6nDnUhQkZO4XTySrTRwLMgozM9R/LyQs2r+Pb tarantino.cs.ucsb.edu,128.111.48.123 ssh-rsa 9SMF4U+qJW03Bh1"
my_list = re.findall(r'(([a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,10})', my_str)
print [i[0] for i in my_list]
```

As Gavin pointed out, you shouldn't use `str` and `list` as variable names because they are built-in types in Python.

Comment: you can just use non-capturing groups `r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,10}'` and `print my_list`

Answer (score 0):

```
In [63]: text = "ctcO6OgnWRAxLtu+akRCFwM asu.edu zOiV6Wo6nDnUhQkZO4XTySrTRwLMgozM9R/LyQs2r+Pb tarantino.cs.ucsb.edu,128.111.48.123 ssh-rsa 9SMF4U+qJW03Bh1"

In [64]: re.findall(r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,10}', text)
Out[64]: ['asu.edu', 'tarantino.cs.ucsb.edu']
```

- Use `(?:...)` to create a non-capturing group. When the pattern contains more than one grouping pattern (i.e. a pattern surrounded by parentheses), `re.findall` returns a tuple for each match. To prevent `re.findall` from returning a list of tuples, use non-capturing groups.
- For the `text` you posted, the pattern `(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.` is unnecessary. There is no literal `-` in `text` so `(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` **never matches anything** in `text`. Of course, you could add  `(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` to the pattern if you wish (note the use of the non-capturing group `(?:...)`), but that part of the pattern is not exercised by the `text` you posted. It would allow you to match names with hypthens, however:

  ```
  In [73]: re.findall(r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,10}', 'asu-psu.edu but not initial hyphens like -psu-asu.edu')
  Out[73]: ['asu-psu.edu', 'psu-asu.edu']
  ```

  And as [Aprillion noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246583/python-domain-name-list-regex/35246711#comment58207282_35246693):

  ```
  In [74]: re.findall(r'(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,10}', text)
  Out[74]: ['asu.edu', 'tarantino.cs.ucsb.edu']
  ```
- See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vG4gS1/1) for an explanation of the pattern `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,10}`